# Https redirection is not working elastic beanstalk nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I know this question was asked many times but I couldn't find a matching case and I'm totally new to AWS so I may be missing something

I read [this page from the official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html#configuring-https-httpredirect.redirect) then used [this file](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/nodejs/https-redirect-nodejs.config) then uploading my application but nothing seems to be changed.

Unfortunately, I'm tied to the current classic load balancer so I can't create a new Application load balancer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> nothing seems to be changed.

The files you showed are for **Amazon Linux 1** (AL1). Since you haven't specified whether you use AL1 or **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2), I assume that the later one is used. This could explain why the files have **no effect** on your environment.

The nginx configuration files in for AL2 are different and should be placed in [different location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). Thus instead of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` you should be using:

```
.platform/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Please note that there are **many differences** between AL1 and AL2, thus the config file as well as other your files may need to be modified:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

Also the files only redirect traffic on the EB instances. Seems to me also that you want to redirect traffic on a load balancer. Sadly CLB **does not support redirects**. For that you would have to use ALB. However, a workaround is presented in the following link:

- [How do I redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS on my Classic Load Balancer in ELB?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/)